# Excel Macro to Highlight All Columns in Selected Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in my workbook that is tied to a hotkey which highlights all columns in the currently selected row. However, it only works if one row is selected. I cant think of a way to adjust it to highlight all the rows if multiple are selected. Here is the code that I am currently using.

```
Sub highlight_done()
'
' highlight_done Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

Dim r As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    
    Range("A" & r & ":Y" & r).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = vbWhite
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like the following, using `Intersect` and `Selection.EntireRow` to get the range to be colored:

```
Sub highlight_done()
'
' highlight_done Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("A:Y"))
    
    With rng.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With rng.Font
        .Color = vbWhite
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```